# Barra de navegação com Nome da empresa

Tags: navegador-de-internet

Como coloco no meu site o nome da Minha empresa na barra de navegação desta forma:

[image: Printscreen de exemplo com o nome do empresa]

Comment: Certificado SSL.

Comment: Isto é que a própria empresa emitiu o certificado de segurança, pois a conexão é via HTTPS, provavelmente no "campo" "`Certificate`" é exibido detalhes/dados para que este nome apareça, não é uma obrigatoriedade e também creio que não implica em melhorar a confiança no site em nível de segurança. Também não é todo navegador que vai mostrar isso, só alguns o fazem.

Answer (score 2):

Isso é uma funcionalidade quando o site usa um Certificado EV SSL (*Extended Validation SSL*), que, além de exibir um cadeado verde, exibe também em verde o nome a empresa ou organização do site.

> A tecnologia de validação avançada EV (Extended Validation) permite
>   aos navegadores a partir do Internet Explorer 7, Firefox 3, Google
>   Chrome, Opera e KDE mostrarem a barra de endereços na cor verde com o
>   nome de sua empresa, permitindo aos usuários identificar o seu site
>   como seguro, autêntico e não clonado.
>   **[Fonte](https://www.rapidssl.com.br/certificado-digital-ssl/evssl.php)**

Para ter o certificado em seu site, é preciso comprá-lo em alguma empresa especializada em segurança digital e serviços de hospedagem e fazer a instalação na sua hospedagem.

Só pra citar algumas empresas que fornecem o certificado:

- [Comodo Brasil](https://www.comodobr.com/produtos.php)
- [Site Blindado](https://www.siteblindado.com)
- [Certisign](https://www.certisign.com.br)
- [GoDaddy](https://br.godaddy.com/)
- [Speedhost](https://www.speedhost.com.br/)

Como é exibido em alguns navegadores populares e modernos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Só para complementando existem vários serviços de SSL gratuitos como o https://letsencrypt.org/ e o https://www.cloudflare.com vc só precisa atentar se o servidor onde o site está instalado tem suporte. Outro detalhe é que no caso do Wordpress por exemplo é preciso instalar um plug-in para colocar configurar o certificado.